# wget: obtaining files matching regex

Tags: linux, unix, download, ftp, wget

According to the man page of **wget**, **--acccept-regex** is the argument to use when I need to selectively transfer files whose names matching a certain regular expression. However, I am not sure how to use **--accept-regex**.

Assuming I want to obtain files *diffs-000107.tar.gz, diffs-000114.tar.gz,  diffs-000121.tar.gz, diffs-000128.tar.gz* in IMDB data directory ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/diffs/. "**diffs\-0001[0-9]{2}\.tar\.gz**" seems to be an ok regex to describe the file names.

However, when executing the following wget command

```
wget -r --accept-regex='diffs\-0001[0-9]{2}\.tar\.gz' ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/diffs/
```

wget indiscriminately acquires all files in the ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/diffs/ directory.

I wonder if anyone could tell what I have possibly done wrong?

Answer (score 12):

Be careful `--accept-regex` is for the complete URL. But our target is some specific files. So we will use `-A`.

For example,

```
wget -r -np -nH -A "IMG[012][0-9].jpg" http://x.com/y/z/
```

will download all the files from IMG00.jpg to IMG29.jpg from the URL.

Note that a matching pattern contains **shell-like wildcards**, e.g. ‘books’ or ‘zelazny196[0-9]*’.

reference:
wget manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html
regex: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading in `wget` man page:

> ```
>   --accept-regex urlregex
>   --reject-regex urlregex
>        Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.
> ```

and noticing that it mentions the *complete* URL (e.g. something like 
 `ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/diffs/diffs-000121.tar.gz`)

So I suggest (without having tried it) to use 
  `--accept-regex='.*diffs\-0001[0-9][0-9]\.tar\.gz'`

(and perhaps give the appropriate `--regex-type` too)

BTW, for such tasks, I would also consider using some scripting language à la Python (or use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or `curl`)

Comment: Thanks, Basile. I tried what you suggested, and even added "--regex-type=posix". But the same problem still exists.